# Join two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL statement for a query:

```
SELECT
    DATE '1900-01-01' + FLOOR("DDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL'1' YEAR+ (MOD("DDate", 1000) -1) * INTERVAL'1' DAY AS "Date",
    LTRIM((SUBSTR("NR8", -6)), '0') AS "Nr",
    CASE WHEN "tEnd" =240000 THEN '23:59:59' ELSE REPLACE(TO_CHAR("tEnd", '00,00,00'),',',':') END AS "End",
    REPLACE(TO_CHAR("zBegin", '00,00,00'),',',':') AS "tStart",
    "Doc1" AS "Doc",
    "Order" AS "Order"
FROM "MP002"."KKI1001"
WHERE   "DDate" >119000
    AND "tFact" = 1

ORDER BY "Date", "Order"
```

Since this is about 15mio records, I would like to receive only necessary data sets.
The Oracle DB "KKI1100" contains the column "Doc1" and the column "Type".
Now, however, I only want all data sets from "KKI1001", which in "KKI1100" om column "Type" contain either an X, X1 or X2.

How should this be implemented?
Using a join and a where clause?
Or is there a more elegant method?

Comment: If you already have the rows your need, plus some more (please correct me if I'm wrong), then you either need information from the second table or you don't. I can't see why reading data from a second table could be a matter of elegance. :-?

Comment: The key for filtering is included in the second tbl "KKI1100" ("Type"), I dont need this column in my first table. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Do you have any control over how the tables and columns are named? If so, please consider removing the case sensitive names, which would remove the need for double-quoting each identifier. If not, you have my sympathies!

Comment: The data model looks gruesome by the way. Date[times] should be stored in columns of the datatype `DATE` in Oracle. Don't use inappropriate data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just inner join the second table to the first table, like so:

```
SELECT DATE '1900-01-01' + floor(k1."DDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL '1' YEAR + (MOD(k1."DDate", 1000) - 1) * INTERVAL '1' DAY AS "Date",
       ltrim((substr(k1."NR8", -6)), '0') AS "Nr",
       CASE
         WHEN k1."tEnd" = 240000 THEN
          '23:59:59'
         ELSE
          REPLACE(to_char(k1."tEnd", '00,00,00'), ',', ':')
       END AS "End",
       REPLACE(to_char(k1."zBegin", '00,00,00'), ',', ':') AS "tStart",
       k1."Doc1" AS "Doc",
       k1."Order" AS "Order"
FROM   "MP002"."KKI1001" k1
       INNER JOIN "KKI1100" k2 ON k1."Doc1" = k2."Doc2" AND k2."Type" IN ('X', 'X1', 'X2')
WHERE  k1."DDate" > 119000
AND    k1."tFact" = 1
ORDER  BY "Date",
          "Order";
```

You could move the `k2."Type" in ('X', 'X1', 'X2') down into the`where` clause; it doesn't really matter for an inner join where the filtering predicate sits (it matters for outer joins, depending on what results you're expecting to see).

N.B. I am assuming that KKI1100."Doc1" is a unique column. If it's not unique, then I would suggest using an `exists` predicate, along the lines of:

```
SELECT DATE '1900-01-01' + floor(k1."DDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL '1' YEAR + (MOD(k1."DDate", 1000) - 1) * INTERVAL '1' DAY AS "Date",
       ltrim((substr(k1."NR8", -6)), '0') AS "Nr",
       CASE
         WHEN k1."tEnd" = 240000 THEN
          '23:59:59'
         ELSE
          REPLACE(to_char(k1."tEnd", '00,00,00'), ',', ':')
       END AS "End",
       REPLACE(to_char(k1."zBegin", '00,00,00'), ',', ':') AS "tStart",
       k1."Doc1" AS "Doc",
       k1."Order" AS "Order"
FROM   "MP002"."KKI1001" k1
WHERE  k1."DDate" > 119000
AND    k1."tFact" = 1
AND    EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   "KKI1100" k2
               WHERE  k2."Type" in ('X', 'X1', 'X2')
               AND    k2."Doc1" = k1."Doc1")
ORDER  BY "Date",
          "Order";
```

Comment: Agree: just join `KKI1001` to `KKI1000`, and filter  `KKI1000` as required If you get actual performance issues you may consider alternate implementations (say make `KKI1000` an inline view), But more likely you'll need to tune the join.

Comment: To me it sounds like the OP wants to look up the second table in order to know whether a related entry exists with one of the given types. That would be an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause ideally. A join might lead to selecting rows multifold, which you'd have to mend with `DISTINCT`. Criteria belongs to the `WHERE` clause in my opinion, not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I suppose I should have added that I'm assuming "Doc1" is a unique column in KKT1100, otherwise yes, you're right - if there could be multiple rows for each "Doc1" value, an exists might be better.

Comment: Thanks, your first approach works fine. Yes, the second table includes the unique key for "doc1".

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, how the tables are related. Is it by the mentioned `Doc1` column in both tables? Anyway, you seem to want an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause. Something like:

```
...
WHERE ddate >119000
AND tfact = 1
AND doc1 IN
(
  SELECT doc1
  FROM kki1100
  WHERE type IN ('X', 'X1', 'X2')
)
ORDER BY "Date", "Order";
```

This has the criteria where it belongs: in the `WHERE` clause. You could use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. I prefer `IN` here for its simplicity.

And when it comes to performance consideration, re-writing the query should be the last thing to come to mind. We'd rather provide appropriate indexes. I don't know about the selectivity of your criteria. Does maybe `tfact = 1` alone lead to very few rows? Or `ddate >119000`? Or only the combination of the two? Or is it rather the restriction on certain KKI1100 entries? Well, you can provide many indexes for about every case, then see which get used and drop the others:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON kki1001 (ddate, tfact, doc1);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON kki1001 (tfact, ddate, doc1);
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON kki1001 (doc1, tfact, ddate);
CREATE INDEX idx4 ON kki1100 (doc1, type);
CREATE INDEX idx5 ON kki1100 (type, doc1);
```